# What are the probable reasons for a slow api?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a asp.netcore 2.0 version. And Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.0.0. My api is taking time in loading mostly it takes 25 to 30 seconds to load. I'm thinking is it related with the asp.netcore version. I would love to get any suggestion from your experience to solve this api slowness. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your workload, If you are doing I/O heavy workloads like massive data writing in disk, Or there is complex SQL query or joining multiple tables, Or if you are calling network operations there (ex: calling third party rest api or etc.) then it can be slow. You can try setting debug pointers and execute lines step by step to check which exact statement is taking time and then work on it.

Comment: Ok ill check on that. But first why it takes time to hit the API.